# Displaying code snippets in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, code-snippets

Ok, not technically a programming question but I want a plugin for my WordPress blog that displays code snippets.

Can anyone here recommend a good one? Also, do you guys know which one Jeff uses on codinghorror. That one looks really good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wordpress.com [claims to use](http://support.wordpress.com/code/) Alex Gorbatchev’s [syntaxhighlighter Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/).

Comment: Thanks Oren, I'm now using http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/syntaxhighlighter/ which is based on Alex's project.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you might be interested in [run-this](http://run-this.appspot.com/) - there is a wordpress plugin to allow your readers to run your snippets in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

For WP-Snippets, I use [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

You should probably use a plugin for escaping characters to be able to display code without having to do it yourself, or your code wont be displayed. Or just put this in functions.php in your theme folder to do this automatically:

```
function bbcode( $attr, $content = null ) {
    $content = clean_pre($content); // Clean pre-tags
    return '<pre"><code>' .
            str_replace('<', '&lt;', $content) . // Escape < chars
            '</code></pre>';
}
add_shortcode('code', 'bbcode');
```

And then wrap your code with `[code]<?php echo 'hello world!'; ?>[/code]`

Source: [Code in posts](http://wp-snippets.com/1711/code-in-posts/)